Giving a data set additional information
I want to give additional information to fungal_tab data set by combining it with taxa_fungi data set. I want to add all the Mycorrhiza information regardless it is ectomycorrhiza or endomycorrhiza. I am trying to use this code in R
myco_tab = fungi_tab %>% 
  data.frame() %>%
    select(which(taxa_fungi$guild ==grepl("\\bmycorrhiza\\b", 
        taxa_fungi$guild)))

but this error message shows up
datatables warning table id=rsGridData - cannot reinitialise datatable

what should I change in my code to avoid this error, so I can get information about fungal taxa in my fungal_tab data set

Hi Dhiemas, Welcome to SO. It sounds like you need to 'merge' or 'join' two dataframes. Can you post some of the contents of myco_tab and fungi_tab. Run dput(head(myco_tab, n=5)) and dput(head(fungi_tab, n=5)) and add the output as an edit of your original post. That way we can likely provide more detailed help.
